# parse multiple digraph in one dot file

Tags: python, dot

I'm trying to process and render some graph in DOT format.
The dot file I have is large (~300MB), and it contains multiple digraphs

```
digraph 1 {...}
digraph 2 {...}
digraph 3 {...}
```

I have got 2 questions:
1. Is it possible to use render only 1 digraph instead of the whole graph?
Something like `dot -3 -Tps mygraph.dot -o out.ps` to render digraph 3 only?

2.What's the best Python library to process dot format?(other languages are also acceptable)
Here are two I tried, but not good enough
**pydot** It gives me a digraph list after importing, which is good, but it doesn't handle "." in the node name. For example `nd.nd [label="nd_node"]` will fail

**pygraphviz** It does handle ".", but only imports digraph 1 when given multiple graph definition in a file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `dot`, you should also have `gvpr`, a graph-processing tool. You can print the third graph with a simple `gvpr` script, like so:

```
BEGIN { int count = 0; }
BEG_G {
    count = count + 1;
    if(count == 3) {
        write($G);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this as a source filter:

```
cat mygraph.dot | gvpr -f thirdgraph.gv | dot -Tps -o out.ps
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but you just need to write a simple parser, or whatever you want to call it. The pygraphviz handles file input by simply read and parse as it would for string input.

So, a sample piece of code would be:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
graph = [[]]
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if declare_new_graph(line):
        graph.append([])
    graph[-1].append(line)

#now you have a list of graphs
#each is a list of lines
#with first line containing the name
#to get the string representation of graph "i"
str = '\n'.join(graph[i])
```